# C++ Input validation (double control)

Tags: c++, validation, input

I'm new to C++.

In a part of a simple project, I have to enter a number and verify that it is positive and not an alphanumeric sequence. With the following code I perform the "check for alphanumeric sequence" but in which way I can add the "positive check"?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

string getline()
{
    string str;
    getline(cin, str);
    return str;
}

int main()
{
int choice;
istringstream iss(getline());
iss >> choice >> ws;
if(iss.fail() || !iss.eof())
{
    cout << "Error" << endl;
}
}
```

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: add `|| choice < 0` to detect negative numbers.

Comment: Off-topic:  Your `getline` function takes more instructions to call than only using `std::getline` where you make the call.  IMHO, get rid of your `getline` function.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight  I tried, but it didn't work!

Comment: I solved with this comment here on StackOverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46541935/7086824). Thank you!

Comment: Voting to close because the problem has been solved. OP, please consider deleting the question by clicking [delete] link below.